# Visual code error when run build task for Unreal engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

[image: Error here]
This was an actor of Unreal engine 5 and I was trying to run build task and the error popped up.
This is simply after creating a new C++ class. I’ve disabled Live Coding. I’ve run Refresh Visual Studio Code Project.

i have looked on google for an hour and it still not working

Comment: oh i found the problem was my setting in environment variables. My ComSpec  was wrong setting so it messed up my visual code.

Comment: When you ask for help about programming post the actual code, not images.